# Center a search bar section in the header in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to center a div with search bar. I tried `position: absolute` with main div `position: relative`. But did not got I wanted. It should go under the text. This is made with Bootstrap 4.

This is what I tried s far.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8uatkngo/)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `top: -114px;` of `.search-sec` and the `position: absolute;` of `.search-align` and add `justify-content: center;` and it works.

See https://jsfiddle.net/aqcredw2/

Oh, and `.fixed-top` should be better `position: sticky;` :)